# Cleat holes "covers" for Shimano shoes

Tags: shimano, shoes

I have a pair of Shimano MW7 shoes, and a pair of Shimano SH-AM9. These shoes are designed for pedals with cleats. But I am often in the situation where

- I have to walk a bit etc
- even worse I have to put the feet down in a the snow or I very cold water

so that I would like to know if Shimano provides covers for the cleat holes on the shoes. (I know for sure that some of their shoes models have these covesr by default, like the XM explorer series for instance.) I tried to contact Shimano by several ways, without any answer.

Comment: You could close the holes with (very) short 4mm bolts. Put a nylon washer under the bolthead.

Comment: Just clarifying, you want to wear these two-hole SPD shoes, without cleats?    Or you're worried about water ingress even around the cleats?  Or are you looking for rubber cleat covers?  Not sure SPD cleats need then, being recessed.

Comment: @Criggie The holes and spaces, on the shoes heels, dedicated to the cleats : I want to cover these holes and spaces.

Comment: With some shoes you can remove the inner sole and cover the holes with tape from the inside.

Comment: Clarifying further, you want to run shoes for cleats, without cleats ?  Why not put the cleat bolts in place?  Or given they're "walkable" put the whole cleat in and leave it there.

Comment: I'm still curious for the "why"; these shoes have recessed cleats so you can specifically walk with them.

Comment: @Criggie my best shoes for platform pedals happen to be my walkable SPDs (with the cleat attached)

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, you want to seal the holes in the sole which are used to mount cleats.

1. Put cleats on.
2. Put the cleat bolts in the holes, but be careful they're not too long when there's no cleat acting as a washer.
3. Put some RTV Silicon sealant up the hole - should be possible to dig this out with a sharp screwdriver or drill later.
4. Short term fix is to slap a square of duct tape over the holes.  Should last for a bit because the shoe sole doesn't touch the ground where the cleat is.

Another option is to wear shoes without cleat holes.

Comment: Most shoes have slots, not holes, so the cleat position can be adjusted.

Comment: @mattnz none of mine do, so that slipped my mind.

Comment: Duct tape on the inside under a removable footbed held up well for 8 months and thousands of km for me, until I removed it because it was too warm. It didn't even leave any glue behind